# How to scale video on a SurfaceView larger than the window on Android?

Tags: android, video, window, scale, surfaceview

Android 2.2 (on a media player boxtop) with a display of 1280x720.

My video is 480px high, 720px wide; standard definition.

I know that if change the layouts of a SurfaceView, the video is scaled to fit whichever is smallest to maintain aspect ratio.

This is great, except I can only scale up to the height of the screen. This is a problem as there is are black bars being broadcast on the top/bottom of the video.
See here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eltK.jpg

I would need to make my SurfaceView (and the window) larger than the screen.

I know about FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, on WindowManager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS

It is supposed to allow my window to expand out past the screen... but I can't seem to get this working. It always seems to resize it to 1280x720px no matter what I do.

If you could help me get this so I can expand my surfaceview video so it looks full screen (clipping the tops video), I will be extremely grateful.

:)

Comment: hi. did you managed to solve this ?thanks mate

Comment: Did you solve your problem?